# Bitshift each element in an array without loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bit-shift

I have an image file with 16 bits/pixel.  Using Matlab, I want to generate another array where each element contains only bits 2-10.  I can do it in a for loop but it is way too slow:

```
if mod(j,2) ~= 0       
   image1(i,j) = bitshift(image(i,j),-2);    % shift the LL bits to the left
else            
   tmp = bitand(image(i,j),3);          % save off the lower 2 bits 00000011
   adder = bitshift(tmp,6);             % shift to new positions in LL
   image1(i,j) = bitshift(image(i,j),-2);  % shift the UL bits to the right
   image1(i,j-1) = bitor(image1(i,j-1),adder);  add in the bits from the UL
end
```

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
 image1(:,1:2:end) = bitshift(image(:,1:2:end),-2); 
 etc
```

Comment: Did you try it the way that you posted? `bitshift` and associated functions all accept multi-dimensional input.

Comment: Yes, the error is "subscripted assignment dimension mismatch".

Comment: Did you try setting `image1 = image` before calling it to make sure that `image1` is the appropriate size?

Comment: Ah!  It was being initialized in a separate function that had switched up the rows/columns.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated with a formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

`bitshift`, `bitand`, and `bitor` call all operate on multi-dimensional arrays as the first input. The issue that you're seeing is likely because you've initialized `image1` to be a different size than `image` and therefore you get a dimension mismatch error with the following command

```
 image1(:,1:2:end) = bitshift(image(:,1:2:end),-2);
```

To fix this, initialize `image1` to either `image` or an array of zeros the size of `image`  prior to calling the above command

```
image1 = zeros(size(image));
image1(:,1:2:end) = bitshift(image(:,1:2:end),-2);
```